# Trouble With Binary Search Tree Construction

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, default-constructor

I have this code written however it is not acting the way it should, when it's run as 
`BST T(arr, 10)`
, how our professor wants it to be, I get an error that there should be a ; before T, but I don't know how I need to change my code top encompass that. Specifically, the professor has it stated like this in the project overview: 
"`BST()` Default constructor, creates an empty tree.

```
BST(int[], int)
```

Constructor, first parameter is an ordered array of elements and the second parameter is the number of elements in the array. The tree should be built in a balanced fashion" 
I also am a bit confused on how I should write my default constructor, should I simply write a code that is `void BST()` without anything passed to it and constructs and empty tree?
Here is my constructor currently.

```
void BST(int * arr, int size)
{
     node * Root = NULL;
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         insert(&Root, arr[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Contructor** 
A constructor will have exact same name as the class and it does not have any return type at all, not even void.

**Default Constructor**
A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments. A possible definition of the default constructor can be like:

```
BST::BST()
{
     node * Root = NULL; 
}
```

A parameterized constructor can be like:

```
BST::BST(int * arr, int size)
{
     node * Root = NULL;
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         insert(&Root, arr[i]);
 }
```

Comment: I realized I hadn't even created the class function for it so I attempted to do so but I'm getting many errors.